# Unpack list of list python

Tags: python

I know this has already been asked in other thread but I recall a neater way of doing this:

so here is a code that i know how to unpack things:

```
list = [[1, "tom"], [4, "jane"], [2, "peter"], [5.5, "Ursala"]]
points=[p for p, n in list]
name=[n for p, n in list]
```

So I know this is how I extract lists from list of list

but i remember there is some neater way of doing this.
It's something like.

```
points,name = list
```

it gives me however the error: *too many values to unpack (expected 2)*

is this method for dictionary? not applicable for list of list?

Comment: Don't. use. `list`. as. variable. name.

Comment: Do *not* name your variable `list`; this is a built-in class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using zip you get tuples, convert those tuples to list using map

`*` is used for unpacking the iterable

```py
l = [[1, "tom"], [4, "jane"], [2, "peter"], [5.5, "Ursala"]]
points,name = map(list, zip(*l))
```

```py
# just to point out numpy is not only for numbers
import numpy as np
l = [[1, "tom"], [4, "jane"], [2, "peter"], [5.5, "Ursala"]]
ln = np.array(l)
points, name = ln[:, 0], ln[:, 1]
```

PS: list is already reserved by python use some other unreserved name

Comment: why not just `points,name =  zip(*l)`

Comment: Hello. What does the asterisk mean? *l?

Comment: @Mohammad that would give tuples, `map(list, ...)` specifically gives lists

Comment: @WileyNg it's of [unpacking an iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists)

Comment: Thanks all so much! you guys are the best!

Comment: Accept if it helps and useful